# How can we run CUDA C program on Hadoop?

Tags: cuda, hadoop

I am trying to use Hadoop to run CUDA C program (not JCUDA). I haven't found any good tutorial or helpful instructions yet.

Could anyone give some advice/links for me? Your help/advice would be highly appreciated.

Regards,

Yik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution may be just writing it as a C program and running it using [Hadoop Streaming](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.15.2/streaming.html)

Comment: Thank you Chris. Could you please provide a general view/idea of using Hadoop Stream to run CUDA C program?

Comment: There is a lot more information on the streaming site, but the idea is that Hadoop Streaming lets you use any executable as a Hadoop mapper or reducer (using stdin and stdout).  Hadoop takes care of moving the data around and running one or more copies of your application on each node (as determined by the mapper/reducer slots available and data structure).  Streaming is the glue that binds your executable in as a mapper and/or reducer.